# Detected implicit cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans Aggregate

Tags: pyspark

I have below join condition,

```
df_data = df1.join(df2, df1.value == df2.value, "inner").select(df1['*'], df2['column'])
```

This join is causing,
**AnalysisException: "Detected implicit cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans\nAggregate**

Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: Could you please share a sample of your input dataframes?

Comment: What version of spark/pyspark are you using?